# Group by in HIVE not working like i want

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Hi so i am trying to output the city with playerid with the most AB(runs).

Output  the birth   city    of  the player  who had the most    at  bats    (AB)    in
his career.

Now i get what i want Cinncinati, sander01, 14432, this is correct. But it shows up in 3's like this. That too for every city and player and runs, like the 2nd most. I only need 1 entry, the other 2 are redundant. I think there something i did wrong with group by, any help? plz

```
Cinncinati, sander01, 14432
Cinncinati, sander01, 14432
Cinncinati, sander01, 14432
Chicago, dere90, 12324
Chicago, dere90, 12324
Chicago, dere90, 12324



SELECT a.bcity,a.id, b.ab FROM master a 
JOIN
(SELECT id, SUM(ab) as ab FROM batting
GROUP by id) b
ON a.id = b.id
ORDER by b.ab DESC
limit 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [DISTINCT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-ALLandDISTINCTClauses) for getting distinct result set.Now coming to your question,join master table with the top row from the result set b.

```
select a.bcity,b.id,b.ab from master a 
join 
(select id,sum(ab) as ab from batting
 group by id
 order by ab desc
 limit 1
) b
on a.id = b.id
```

You can change the LIMIT 30 to LIMIT 1 and get the same result.

```
SELECT a.bcity,a.id, b.ab FROM master a 
JOIN
(SELECT id, SUM(ab) as ab FROM batting
 GROUP by id
) b
ON a.id = b.id
ORDER by b.ab DESC
 limit 1;
```

Note: if there are multiple players with the same most runs then LIMIT 1 will not give the correct answer.

Comment: thank you once again,  but hey quick suggestion. you have to have an alias for sum(ab) in order by clause, other wise it will throw udf SUM not supported.

Comment: @dedpo in group by or order by?

Comment: order by, my mistake